Accessing Azure Key Vault in a Windows Server Container on an on-prem hybrid joined server with managed identities
I am working on configuring an on-prem Windows Server 2022 production web server that is hybrid joined to Azure using Azure Arc. I will be running windows containers hosting asp.net core applications. The applications will use Azure Key vault for secret management. I would like for the application to use the hosts managed identity to access the key vault. I am using DefaultAzureCredential in the applications. On the host server I am able to access the keyvault with a sample application but when running this app inside the container I am not able to access it, and I get an error that ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed. What do I need to give the container for it to use the host server's identity to access the key vault?
The app I am testing with is a console app. My program.cs is
using Azure.Core;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var keyVaultName = "your-key-vault-name";
var secretName = "your-secret-name";
var kvUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/";
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

try
{
  KeyVaultSecret secret = await client.GetSecretAsync(secretName);
  Console.WriteLine($"Secret Value: {secret.Value}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Failed to retrieve secret: {ex.Message}");
}

My docker file is for a windows server
My Docker command is
docker run -it --rm -e IDENTITY_ENDPOINT=$Env:IDENTITY_ENDPOINT -e IMDS_ENDPOINT=$Env:IMDS_ENDPOINT -v C:\azuretest:C:\azuretest --name my-app-container mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2022 cmd

The error I am getting is
Failed to retrieve secret: DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/defaultazurecredential/troubleshoot
- EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/environmentcredential/troubleshoot
- WorkloadIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. The workload options are not fully configured. See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/workloadidentitycredential/troubleshoot
- ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. No response received from the managed identity endpoint.
- Visual Studio Token provider can't be accessed at C:\Users\ContainerUser\AppData\Local\.IdentityService\AzureServiceAuth\tokenprovider.json
- Azure CLI not installed
- PowerShell is not installed.
- Azure Developer CLI could not be found.

When I try using the host server IP address I get the following error
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

When I try just mapping the environment variables, I get the following error
Failed to retrieve secret: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed:

I tried mapping the IMDS environment variables, opening port 4032 on the host firewall, and using the host IP address but still receive this error.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

#1 Share a full log of the error. #2 Is you container based on linux? Share the dockerfile

@JRichardsz I updated the post to include this info

@BrandonG Container can't access keyvault through managed identity running inside windows server 2022. Through Azure ARC windows server 2022 will have Its Managed identity but as containers run in isolated environment therefore it can't access Windows server 2022's managed identity to access key vault.

Use a service principal to connect using secret or certificate.

Thanks @VivekVaibhavShandilya

@BrandonG using service principal were you able to access Key vault secret?

@VivekVaibhavShandilya We decided to not use containers for now and just use IIS. However, I am not having any luck with IIS authenticating using managed identity. I believe it is something related to permissions.

@BrandonG did you assign role Key Vault Secrets User or Access in access policy to the managed identity in Key Vault.

@VivekVaibhavShandilya I needed to add the applicationpoolidentity to the proper security group on the server and have the app pool Load the profile. Everything is working thanks

As I Mentioned in comment.

Windows containers run in an isolated environment, it cannot directly inherit the host machine’s managed identity. Because the containers run in isolated environment.

Workaround is to use a service principal instead of managed identity to authenticate against Azure Key Vault in containers when running inside the On-Prem. Create a service principal in Azure AD, assign the this role Key Vault Secrets User, and provide its credentials (client ID, secret, or certificate) within the container to access Key Vault secrets.


Worked - Switching to IIS for Managed Identity and using ApplicationPoolIdentity:

Running the application in IIS in On-Prem Windows Server 2022 machine instead of using Containers.
Adding the ApplicationPoolIdentity to the required security groups on the server.
Assigning the managed identity to the required role in Azure key vault Key Vault Secrets User.
Configuring the application pool to load the user profile to authenticate.

By switching from containers to IIS, the application had direct access to the host’s managed identity, making the authentication process more straightforward.
